# netsh advfirewall firewall (set Allow if encrytped)

Tags: windows, batch-file, firewall, netsh

I am trying to use "netsh advfirewall firewall add rule" to create a windows firewall rule.

How can I set the "action" parameter to "Allow the connection if secure" and require connections to be encrypted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`security=authenc` with either `action=allow` or `action=bypass` depending upon your particular requirements.